# Becrowd problem 1161. The system says that Wrong answer (100%)

Tags: javascript

Read two numbers M and N indefinitely. Calculate and write the sum of their factorial. Be carefull, because the result can have more than 15 digits.

Input
The input file contains many test cases. Each test case contains two integer numbers M (0 ≤ M ≤ 20) and N (0 ≤ N ≤ 20). The end of file is determined by eof.

Output
For each test case in the input your program must print a single line, containing a number that is the sum of the both factorial (M and N).

```
// this the code i have writen but it says 100% wrong answar.
// On the other hand i check the code in vscode, it is work properly
// Then what was wrong 

var input = require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin', 'utf8');
var lines = input.split('\n');
var line = lines.shift().split(" ");
const M = parseInt(line[0]);
const N =parseInt(line[1]);
const fact = (M,N)=>{
    let s1 = 1;
    let s2  =1;
    if(M===0)
        s1 = 1;
    else{
        for(let i =1; i<=M; i++)
            s1=s1*i;
    }
    if(N===0)
        s2 = 1;
    else{
        for(let j =1; j<=N; j++)
            s2=s2*j;
    }
    const sum = s1+s2;
    return sum;
}
const result = fact(3,2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not sure how big your numbers actually are (if overflow is possible), but if you know you'll be working with large integers consider the use of [`bigint`](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_bigints.html) datatype instead of `number`. You'd only have to add some `n` postfix to your numbers and would be working with `bigint`

Comment: You actually never use the M and N from the file.  I don't know if that was for the example or that is how your code is actually done.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you seperate the calculate factorial code in another function and re-use it. And if the number you want to find factorial of that is 0 or 1, it's factorial will be 1. But you check only `M === 0` and `N === 0`. Here is my way of finding the factorial and return the sum of them.

```js
function calCulateFactorial(n){
  let answer = 1;
  if (n == 0 || n == 1){
    return answer;
  } else if(n > 1){
    for(var i = n; i >= 1; i--){
      answer = answer * i;
    }
    return answer;
  }
}

function fact(M, N) {
    const fact1 = calCulateFactorial(M)
    const fact2 = calCulateFactorial(N)
    return fact1 + fact2
}

const result = fact(5, 2)
console.log(result) // 122
```

Comment: I have checked your code. It is absolutely right. But BeCrowd says 100% wrong answer. I jiust add these in you code___                                                                                                                                   var input = require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin', 'utf8');
var lines = input.split('\n');

const line = lines.shift().split(" ");
const a = parseInt(line[0]);
const b = parseInt(line[1]);

const result = fact(a, b);
console.log(result) ;